# How to include authentication token in a jenkinsfile script to trigger build remotely?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins UI, there's an option to set `Authentication Token` under `Build Trigger`--> `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)`. Any configuration change needs to be done through a jenkins script.
How do i set the authentication token in a jenkins script?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JobDSL Plugin to create and manage Jobs in a Jenkinsfile:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-authenticationToken

Basic example:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Demo') {
      steps {
        jobDsl scriptText: '''
          job('demo') {
            authenticationToken("this-is-just-an-example-token")
            steps {
              shell('echo Hello World!')
            }
          }
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```